# Avoiding a redirect before a 404

Tags: seo

When a request comes into my site without a trailing slash, e.g., `/about`, I redirect to `/about/` before serving any content. If a user requests a non-existant URL, they'll receive a 302 redirect before getting their 404. Our (very trustworthy) SEO team tells me that this confuses search engines, and that only having the 404 is key. I believe this, but I'm not totally sure I understand why. Can someone explain the technical reasoning?

Comment: If they are really a trustworthy SEO team then they should be able to tell you why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should serve 404 without any redirect, as if you  are redirecting away from the page it's not the removed page that is returning a 404.  I will give an example where this might cause problems.

So you have a page which you decide to remove that is indexed in Google. You remove the page and it now 302 redirects to a 404 page. However as a 302 redirect is a temporary redirect this removed page will stay in Google's results, as you are telling Google it's only temporarily moved. If the actual url returns a 404 page the page will over time drop out of Google's index.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete moobot's good answer, Google doesn't like at all 302 redirections (redirect temporarily) ; it prefers 301 redirections (redirect permanently).

For SEO, there are two good ways to follow (as you wish, each choice is good):
1) redirecting bad url or old page to a personal 404 page
2) redirecting bad url or old page to the most pertinent page of your site

In any case, 302 redirections are bad pratices in SEO.

Comment: Google does not think 302s are bad. You should use the right redirect in the right situation